# How to manage TextFormField paddings and margins in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textformfield

[image]

Hello users,

I want to use multiple TextFormFields in a container but it seems default Forms take too much space. How to manage to space between TextFormFields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `isDense: true` it will shrink the TextFormField

```
TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              isDense: true
            ),
          )
```